# Usar alias para SELECT en Informix de carga de DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, informix

Se puede cambiar utilizar un alias de la columna de la tabla de la Base de Datos para cargar como nombre de la columna del DataGridView, para hacerla descriptiva para el usuario?

Select que Funciona:

```
select id_vehiculo as IDVehiculo, fechahora as Realizada from inspeccion where = X
```

Selects que no funcionan:

```
select id_vehiculo as ID Vehiculo, fechahora as Fecha Realizada from inspeccion where = X

select id_vehiculo as "ID Vehiculo", fechahora as "Fecha Realizada" from inspeccion where = X

select id_vehiculo as 'ID Vehiculo', fechahora as 'Fecha Realizada' from inspeccion where = X
```

Comment: Autogenere?? en propiedades del DGV? Porque "auto" no encuentro ninguno que se parezca

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8 . La documentacion es tu amiga muchas veces ;) esa es una propiedad del control tambien.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar nombres compuestos en el AS de informix, necesitas usar una variable de entorno segun como se explica [aca](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_233.htm).

La variable es DELIMIDENT y hay que usarla en la cadena de conexion de la siguiente forma:

```
Database=mydatabase;Host=192.168.100.1;Max Pool Size=3;
Min Pool Size=1;Pooling=True;Protocol=onsoctcp;Password=informix;
Server=ol_server;Service=1256;User ID=informix;delimident=y
```

Creditos: [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3759381/73749)

Comment: recomiendan no meterse con DELIMIDENT.... que hago... :P

Comment: Yo siempre trato de generar las columnas a mano.. y santo remedio.. siempre... @Vizz3rdriX

Comment: El autogenerate no me funcionó, sigue poniendo los datos en crudo desde la BD, el comando lo tiro directo en linux o donde?

Comment: Como que no te funciono? tenes que poner como nombre de display el que queres, y como el nombre que conecta el que viene de la base de datos. y a que te referis con el comando? ese es un ejemplo de cadena de conexion. vos sabras como es tu cadena de conexion a la db @Vizz3rdriX

Comment: el alias no funciono con as solo, lo de la conexion la hacemos por el driver ODBC. La solución fue recorrer liena por linea del recordset y asignarlo a cada una de las celdas de cada una de las filas, con repeticiones, habiendo creado las columnas previamente. Gracias por la paciencia igualmente.

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX si le asignas el datasource no agarra las columnas? estan haciendo algo mal, porque asi deberia funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: No, deja las columnas que yo creo vacías y las que trae de la tabla con sus datos acopladas a la derecha, pero como dije, logramos hacerlo por otro lado, pero digamos que mata la escalabilidad del programa, igualmente es proyecto de finalización de curso